# Docker Container on Windows 11, cant access the Laptop's cam

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, webcam, docker-for-windows

I have a flask app that detects Personal Protection Equipment (PPE) using Yolov8 in video streamed via Laptop's camera,

Problem is: When I run the app without Docker, it runs and streams the cam feed on the browser normally BUT running the app with Docker, the app does not stream anything on the browser

I am running docker from Windows based laptop, when I tried to add device path using this [nearest documentation to my problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/hardware-devices-in-containers#run-a-container-with-a-device) and I tried to get the absolute path of my camera using the [info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-device-interface-classes). It failed,

I build the docker image using

`docker build --tag flask-ppe .`

I run the docker image using the following command

`docker run --isolation=process --device="USB\VID_0C45&PID_6730&MI_00\7&246BA97E&0&0000" -p 5000:5000 flask-ppe`

I can not resolve this problem, here is my DockerFile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Install OpenCV Dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1 libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender-dev libxext6 -y

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /ppe-live-detector

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5000

# Define the command to run your application
CMD ["python", "app.py", "--enable-video-capture"]
```

The error I always get is the following one and then the browser stops
[image: Flask app error when running it via Docker]

The last option that I do not feel like it is a smart thing to do is to use Virtual Machines, which IMO negates the whole concept of using Docker

PLEASE FEEL FREE TO CORRECT ME and/or EDIT my question

Comment: debug with VLC or guvcview or ffmpeg, instead of opencv.